# Grouped RPC calls / more efficient reads

Tags: anchor, rpc, jsonrpc-api, helius

I am fetching the account state of multiple solana accounts via a nonce type structure. For example, I have accounts where I have nonce 1, nonce 2, nonce 3, etc...

I'm am fetching all the states on the client side and returning in user.

In EVM land, I am able to batch calls together using [Multicall](https://docs.uniswap.org/contracts/v3/reference/periphery/base/Multicall). This allows multiple reads in one call, saving RPC calls.

Are there any equivalents in anchor / solana land?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`let accs = await getMultipleAccounts(program.provider, [acc1, acc2, ...])` is great if you have many keys, but it does tend to be slower than getting a single account. It also has an upper limit, around 100, beyond that you need to split into multiple calls to getMultipleAccounts.

If you have several keys (say less than a dozen), you may just want to fetch in parallel:

```
    const [acc1, acc2, ....etc] = await Promise.all([
      program.account.acc.fetch(acc1Key),
      program.account.acc.fetch(acc2Key),
      ...etc
    ]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Technically you can send multiple JSON-RPC requests by just passing an array:

```
curl https://api.devnet.solana.com -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '
[
    {
        "jsonrpc": "2.0",
        "id": 1,
        "method": "getAccountInfo",
        "params": [
            "AfFRmCFz8yUWzug2jiRc13xEEzBwyxxYSRGVE5uQMpHk",
            {
                "encoding": "jsonParsed"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "jsonrpc": "2.0",
        "id": 1,
        "method": "getBalance",
        "params": [
            "83astBRguLMdt2h5U1Tpdq5tjFoJ6noeGwaY3mDLVcri"
        ]
    }
]
'
```

This is documented in the RPC docs: https://arc.net/l/quote/ndyosvwc

But many RPCs will restrict a lot of batch requests and they're generally not recommended.

In your case can you use [getMultipleAccounts](https://docs.solana.com/api/http#getmultipleaccounts)? That will fetch the state of many accounts in a single RPC call.